# Time page load is difference on two sub domains but same source code

Tags: php, nginx

I use an strange issue like that:
There is two subdomains: sub1.domain.com and sub2.domain.com add to SERVER 1 , then proxy to SERVER 2.
They have same source code and database. When I do a post request for an action in application, the execute time is not same, sub1.domain.com is very slow.
My server is nginx, database is mariadb, OS is CentOS7+
Could anyone support me about:

- How can I detect the root issue ?
- Which tool can I setup to trace ?
- What is type of this bug ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You should profile the application on both servers to see where the application takes the most amount of time. Nginx logs might also reveal the source of the problem. XDebug is an excellent tool for profiling PHP.

Without many details, it's impossible for anyone here to tell for sure though.

Comment: I guest that the root issue in cache network ? TFB is different between two subdomains. Evently, when I create sub3.domain.com , it still run faster than sub1.domain.com with same request.